# Привязка внешнего ключа при добавлении нового значения в таблицу master-detail

Tags: sql, база-данных, delphi, delphi-7, relation

Всем доброго дня. Имеются 2 таблицы, связанные master-detail. При добавлении нового значения в таблицу detail не привязывается внешний ключ, выбранный с таблицы master.

Сама связь M-D осуществляется на форме при помощи двух DBLookUpComboBox'ов и DataSource,ADOQuery на каждый соответственно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С помощью кнопок [+] добавляются новые значения, которых нет в комбобоксах. Но проблемы начинаются на втором [+] (он же detail), при создании новой строки, нужно чтобы он привязывал внешний ключ с предыдущего LookUpComboBox (Master).
Код кнопки [+]:

```
begin
Form4.ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
Form4.ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('Select Специальность from Специальность WHERE   Специальность='+#39+Form5.DBEdit1.Text+#39); //проверка на повтор
Form4.ADOQuery1.Open;
if Form4.ADOQuery1.IsEmpty then
  begin
  Form4.Query_spec.FieldByName('Специальность').AsString := Form5.DBEdit1.Text; //ПРОБЛЕМА ГДЕ-то ЗДЕСЬ! Добавляет новое значение без привязка внешнего ключа
  Form4.Query_spec.Open;
  Form4.Query_spec.Post;
  MessageBox(Handle, 'Новые данные занесены','Добавление нового значения',MB_ICONINFORMATION);
  end
 else
  begin
  Form4.Query_spec.Cancel;
  Form4.ADOQuery1.Cancel;
  MessageBox(Handle,PChar(''+Form5.DBEdit1.text+' уже есть в списке!'),'Ошибка',MB_ICONWARNING);
  end;
 end;
```

Новое значение записывается в DBEdit1. У него привязка соответственная есть к таблицам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил так:

```
Form4.Query_spec.FieldByName('Специальность').AsString := Form5.DBEdit1.Text;
  Form4.Query_spec.fieldbyname('Код вида').AsInteger:= Form4.Query_vid.FieldByName('Код_vid').asInteger;
```